# Covariance Matrix lm object R

Tags: r, regression

This should be really easy, but is there a built-in function in R to get an unbiased estimate of the variance covariance model of an lm object? And then I mean $\epsilon \epsilon' / (n-k-1)$? Because using `cov(lm$resid)` does not adjust for the number of variables $k$, or does it?

I know how to program this manually of course, but I was just curious whether there is no built-in function. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that, assuming the fitted model `lm1`, you want simply `summary(lm1)$sigma`.

Yes, your intuition is correct; `cov(lm$resid)` will not adjust for the degrees of freedom.